# how can I create a long String from a Clob?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, oracle10g

```
// Load the database details into the variables.
String url      = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
String user     = "scott";
String password = "tiger";

// Create the properties object that holds all database details
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", user );
props.put("password", password);
props.put("SetBigStringTryClob", "true");

try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( url     , props );


            // Create a PreparedStatement object
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

            // Create a ResultSet to hold the records retrieved.
            ResultSet rset = null;

            // Create SQL query statement to retrieve records having CLOB data from
            // the database.
            String sqlCall = query; 
            pstmt= conn.prepareStatement(sqlCall);

            // Execute the PrepareStatement
            rset = pstmt.executeQuery();

            //String clobVal = null;

            // Get the CLOB value larger than 32765 bytes from the resultset
            while (rset.next()) {

                String clobVal =  rset.getString(1);
                System.out.println(clobVal);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm trying to convert Clob data as String using JDBC. I have the above code but it returns null from database and I don't understand why.
I have made one function in oracle which converts well but it's very slow in processing.

How can I create a long String from a Clob using JDBC? I'm using oracle10g

Comment: If `getString()` returns `NULL` this either means your column is `NULL` or you have an outdated driver. `getString()` on a CLOB column works fine with any recent driver.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html#retrieve_clob

You should use the method [getClob(int pos)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html) from the ResultSet object .
From the Clob object you can get a Reader or the String with the getCharacterStream() or getSubString() methods.